# SQL driver error laravel. Seeder works but from controller doesn't

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model

Working on a project I got stuck on the following thing. When I run the seeder in ssh it works perfectly but when I'm doing a call on the same model **User** inside a controller, the following error appears:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: could not find driver
```

It doens't make sense that the seeder works perfectly but by a controller it doesn't.

Controller call:

```
$user = User::where('email', $mail)->firstOrFail()
```

Seeder call:

```
$user = User::create([
        'name' => 'foo',
        'email' => 'foo@bar.com'
    ]);
```

I already checked the following:

- Same model
- .env database is correctly (Need to be else I didn't get any result on seeder)
- Driver exist (Need to be else I didn't get any result on seeder)

What else could it be?

Comment: Make sure that the driver is installed for both the CLI and Web/FPM versions of PHP. Since the seeder works, it should be for the CLI, but try adding a file in the public directory with `<?php phpinfo();`, then open that page to make sure all of the drivers are installed correctly

Comment: Thanks, checked specially and the following result, MySQL driver for PDO is installed but pdo driver saids "no value", but when i installed pdo it said already installed.

Comment: how you are running seeds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, the driver was enabled but without any driver. After Ubuntu 14.xx you need to define the actual php version instead of installing without a version number.

```
sudo apt-get install php8.0-mysql
```

In my situation I use the above command and it fixed my issue.